# Altium user interface question

Tags: altium

I am learning Altium designer. In PCB library design window the mechanical position information box is moving with cursor. How do I dock it to the window?
[image]

I tired to reset the interface to defaults from preferences. It did not help.

Comment: I think that is called the "heads up display". Try to find an option (maybe in "Preferences") to disable it (Sorry I don't know where; I turned it off years ago and never thought about it again). The cursor position will still be available at the lower left of the screen.

Comment: @ThePhoton Tons of thanks. I found it in View -> Board Insight. It was extremely disturbing for me as it cluttered up the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The credit for this answer should go to @ThePhoton who helped me. This is for future where one get stuck. One should disabled it in View -> Board Insight. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Anybody else bothered by "Reset**s** Heads Up Delta Origin"?